# How do I stop the sound from an embedded youtube video?

Tags: html

I want an embedded YouTube video to auto play but with no sound. How can I do that? I have embedded the video with iframe tags. This is my code:

```
<iframe
       src= https://www.youtube.com/embed/NpEaa2P7qZI>
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `mute=1` to the end of your link.

`<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NpEaa2P7qZI?mute=1"></iframe>`